# Send graph as email body using powershell

Tags: excel, powershell

I am having below code to create graph using powerhsell Import-Excel

```
$outputXLSX = "C:\report_10_02.xlsx"
$data = Import-Excel -Path $outputXLSX


$cd = New-ExcelChartDefinition -XRange Name -YRange Count -ChartType ColumnStacked3D -Height 300 -Title "Latency Count" -Width 1000 -SeriesHeader Count
$data | Export-Excel $outputXLSX -ExcelChartDefinition $cd -AutoNameRange #-WorksheetName "Sheet2"
```

I need **excel file as mail attachment** and **graph as email body**.

Please let me know how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

I have answered an question to mails from PowerShell before and this should help you:

```
$Outlook = New-Object -ComObject Outlook.Application
$Mail = $Outlook.CreateItem(0)
$Mail.To = "xyz@outlook.com"
$Mail.Subject = "Your Subject"
$Mail.Body = "Your Text"
$mail.attachments.add("C:\Users\YourUser\Documents\test.txt") #path to file
$Mail.Send()
```

If it works with Export-Excel is something I do not know, but you can easily try it out by using:

```
$mail.attachments.add(Export-Excel)
```

Comment: Thanks for you response. have one doubt. will it put the graph in the email body?

Comment: @EmptyCoder Oh I missunderstood your request. If it wouldn't work with $mail.body.add(Export-Excel) - mind that I add it to the body, not attachment - then I know of no valid way to do it.